# How to delete some columns from CSV in Unix?

Tags: shell, csv, unix, awk, sed

I have a file of 17 columns with comma delimiter & double quotes if there is any comma available in the value. There's an example below with few columns

```
Jim,State,123456,Region1,759358,Yes,District1,
"frank, jr",State,789123,"Region2,Dummy",12345,No,District2,
```

I tried this code

```
sed 's/[^,]*,//' file
```

I am getting the output

```
State,123456,Region1,759358,Yes,District1,
 jr",State,789123,"Region2,Dummy",12345,No,District2,
```

But I need the output as

```
State,123456,Region1,759358,Yes,District1,
State,789123,"Region2,Dummy",12345,No,District2,
```

Actually after removing the first column I need to load these values in the table. So the comma delimeter should work perfectly then only it will load. I can only use awk or sed to achieve this.

Comment: I have updated the question with better example.

Comment: Into which rdbms will you load? And by which tool of that rdbms will you use to perform the load?  Some loading tools have built-in options to skip columns in delimited input files, meaning you then do not need to pre-process the file. Other tools let you load the file "as is" into a temporary table, then copy only the columns of interest into the real target table. Whatever is easiest...

Comment: @mao : its Netezza, I am using the NZLOAD to load the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^("[^"]*"|[^,]*),//' file
```

Remove from the start of the line, any double quoted field or any non-comma characters, followed by a comma.

Answer (score 2):

Better use a real CSV parser [csvkit](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit):

```
$ csvcut -c2- file.csv
```

---

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and [`Text::CSV_XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) parser:

```
perl -MText::CSV_XS -nE '
    BEGIN{our $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new()}
    $csv->parse($_) or die $!;
    my @F = $csv->fields();
    say join ",", @F[1..$#F]
' file
```

---

You can also use [miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller)

---

With [imported extra functions](http://mcollado.z15.es/xgawk/csvmode/):

(requires `gawk` version >= 4.1.0 )

```
gawk '@include "csvmode1"; {$1=""; sub("^"OFS, "")} 1' file.csv
```

---

With `gawk`, using [`FPAT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html):

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","; FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"} {$1=""; sub("^"OFS, "")} 1' file.csv
```

Comment: This csvcut command is not working in my shell.

Comment: What is the error? 'is not working' on a professional web site is pointless. You need to install `csvkit`

Comment: I'm sorry. I am working on client machine & I am not allowed to install anything. I just have to work with basic unix command like sed, awk to achieve this output.

Comment: Check `awk` version.

Answer (score 1):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
{ if (match($0,/"[^"]*",/))
     start = RLENGTH+1
  else { 
     match ($0,/,/)
     start = RSTART+1
  }
  print substr($0,start)
}' file
```

This generates:

```
State,123456,Region1,759358,Yes,District1,
State,789123,"Region2,Dummy",12345,No,District2,
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a language which has robust support for CSV data, such Python. Here is a simple script:

```py
import csv

with open("data.csv") as instream, open("out.csv", "w") as outstream:
    reader = csv.reader(instream)
    writer = csv.writer(outstream)

    for row in reader:
        del row[0]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

This script assumes your input file is called "data.csv" and writes output to "out.csv"

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, your easiest best bet is some form of CSV parser.

Here is a Ruby:

```
ruby -r csv -e '
puts CSV.generate{|csv| 
CSV.parse($<.read).each{|row| csv<<row[1..]}}' file
```

Or you can use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
mlr --csv -N cut -x -f 1 then cat file
```

Either prints:

```
State,123456,Region1,759358,Yes,District1,
State,789123,"Region2,Dummy",12345,No,District2,
```